# in beamer, change fontsize of selected slides with nested lists

Tags: beamer, fontsize

I want to change the font size of particular frames, and when I use

```
\fontsize{<font size>}{<value for \baselineskip>}\selectfont
```

as suggested by [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33973/14127), I found it does not change the font size inside nest lists. Is there a way to change those font size accordingly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a `\ChangeItemFont` command allowing you to change the font for the three valid nesting levels in an itemize environment, defined in the `beamer` way; the syntax is

```
\ChangeItemFont{<font commands 1st level>}{<font commands 2nd level>}{<font commands 3rd level>}
```

The code and an example with some crazy font sizes in the first frame, just for illustration:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\ChangeItemFont[3]{%
\renewcommand{\itemize}[1][]{%
  \beamer@ifempty{##1}{}{\def\beamer@defaultospec{#1}}%
  \ifnum \@itemdepth >2\relax\@toodeep\else
    \advance\@itemdepth\@ne
    \beamer@computepref\@itemdepth% sets \beameritemnestingprefix
    \usebeamerfont{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
    \usebeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body begin}%
    \list
      {\usebeamertemplate{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}}
      {\def\makelabel####1{%
          {%
            \hss\llap{{%
                \usebeamerfont*{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}%
                \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}####1}}%
          }%
        }%
  \ifnum\@itemdepth=1\relax
    #1%
  \else
  \ifnum\@itemdepth=2\relax
    #2%
  \else
  \ifnum\@itemdepth=3\relax
    #3%
  \fi%
  \fi%
  \fi%
  }
  \fi%
  \beamer@cramped%
  \raggedright%
  \beamer@firstlineitemizeunskip%
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Font size changed}
\ChangeItemFont{\fontsize{30}{36}\selectfont}{\scriptsize}{\LARGE}
\begin{itemize}
\item First item.
  \begin{itemize}
  \item First subitem.
    \begin{itemize}
    \item First subsubitem.
    \item Second subsubitem.
    \item Third subsubitem.
    \item Fourth subsubitem.
    \end{itemize}
  \item Second subitem.
  \end{itemize}
\item Second item.
\item Third item.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Regular font size}
\begin{itemize}
\item First item.
  \begin{itemize}
  \item First subitem.
    \begin{itemize}
    \item First subsubitem.
    \item Second subsubitem.
    \item Third subsubitem.
    \item Fourth subsubitem.
    \end{itemize}
  \item Second subitem.
  \end{itemize}
\item Second item.
\item Third item.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This answer is close to what I want to do in a separate question but I just cannot understand what is going on...where in your command are you actually changing the font size??

Comment: @Gonzalo What about enumerate environment? It seems it is not working for that environment

Answer (score 1):

To achieve a very similar goal I generally use the following:

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Size changed}
\scalebox{0.8}{\begin{minipage}{1.20\textwidth}

... your content here ...

\end{minipage}}
\end{frame}
```

I do not know how to compute the combined values of the scale factor and of the minipage width, I generally try several values until it satisfies me.

For example, the following content:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item First item.
  \begin{itemize}
  \item First subitem.
    \begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[75]
    \item \lipsum[66]
    \item \lipsum[75]
    \end{itemize}
  \item Second subitem.
  \end{itemize}
\item Second item.
\item Third item.
\end{itemize}
```

gives:

[image]

and if you change the scale/minipage values to 0.6/1.6 you obtain:

[image]

Comment: Maybe you would like to have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/313736/36296 I think, your solution might also work there.

Comment: @samcarter Thanks for your comment; do you think I should copy the proposed answer to the question mentioned in your comment or just make a link (I am not used to the habits in tex.stackexchange) ?

Comment: As the other question is a bit more general, maybe you could add a table or block to your code and post an "extended" version for the other question? That's what I would probably do.

Comment: And welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Comment: @samcarter I posted an enriched solution proposal for the other question (with a centered table & scale factor). Thanks for your welcome & help.