# Decrease font size on a listing in beamer

Tags: beamer, fonts, itemize

I want to decrease the font size on a bullet list on a beamer frame.

My code is:

```
\begin{frame}{Title}
\begin{itemize}

 \item Item 1 here
 \item Item 2 here

\end{itemize}

\end{frame}
```

I have tried to use this suggestion: [in beamer, change fontsize of selected slides with nested lists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130540/in-beamer-change-fontsize-of-selected-slides-with-nested-lists), but this changes the font size without changing the bullet size ...

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The triangle is hard-coded in its size. Therefore its definition needs to be adapted. The original definition can be found in `beamerinnerthemedefault.sty`:

```
\defbeamertemplate*{itemize item}{default}{%
  \scriptsize\raise1.25pt\hbox{\donotcoloroutermaths$\blacktriangleright$}}
```

Example, which makes the triangle smaller and sets the font to `\footnotesize`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}

\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate body}{size=\footnotesize}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{%
  \footnotesize
  \raise1pt\hbox{\donotcoloroutermaths$\scriptstyle\blacktriangleright$}%
}

\begin{itemize}

 \item Item 1 here
 \item Item 2 here

\end{itemize}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That works perfectly thanks! Could you please tell me how to make it even smaller?

Comment: @volcompt Smaller than `\footnotesize` does not make much sense, if the there are people, which wants to read the slide. Smaller than `\footnotesize` is `\scriptsize` and `\tiny`. The parameter for `\raise` needs an adjustment, originally `1.25pt` to smaller values. `\scriptscriptstyle` is smaller than `\scriptstyle`. An alternative is putting the itemize symbol in `\scalebox` or `\resizebox` of package `graphicx`.