# How to change Fonts while using AMS-package?

Tags: beamer, fonts, amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts

Can I use another font and another size with those packages? I don't like the way, the font turned out in my document(beamer). It is too big and the distance between lines should be smaller.

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{eurosym}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{lmodern} 

\renewcommand\textbullet{\ensuremath{\bullet}}

% Darstellung -----------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
```

Comment: Do you want to change the entire text to some standard fonts like `Times, Palatino`, etc.?

Comment: Yes. I want to change the entire text to another font

Comment: Unrelated: `amssymb` already loads `amsfonts` so that line is not needed. You may want to have a look at the font catalogue: http://www.tug.org/FontCatalogue/

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem.

Comment: The main font you have specified is `lmodern`.  This has nothing to do with the AMS fonts; they are only "add-ons" for math.  See the FontCatalogue as recommended by @daleif.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are the updated code to change the font, `newtxtext,newtxmath` are the packages used for Times font, and `newpxtext,newpxmath` are the packages for Palatino font, etc. You can change what you like...

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{eurosym}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{lmodern} 

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\renewcommand\textbullet{\ensuremath{\bullet}}

% Darstellung -----------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}

This is for test

\end{document}
```

Comment: So the font actually changed! But it is way to thick and big. How can I change that?

Comment: @CarolinWeber Sorry, may I know what you meant for `thick and big`?

Comment: So I wish, that the size of the font would be a little bit smaller. Because my slides look very full.. (or maybe there is a font which is more useful for a cleaner look on slides?)

Comment: Standard font size starts from `10pt` to `12pt`, if you want to decrease still, you can...

Comment: So how can I decrease the entire size of the font?

Comment: Can you confirm which `template` you are using?

Comment: \usetheme{Boadilla} do you mean this with template?

Comment: No, template or `.cls` file, which are in the command `\documentclass{...}`

Comment: \documentclass[handout]{beamer}

Comment: This link https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251715/decrease-font-size-on-a-listing-in-beamer may helps you...