# Cannot control font size of nested itemize environments in beamer

Tags: beamer, fontsize, itemize

In beamer, I am only able to control the font size of the items in the first level `itemize` environment (using `\fontsize{}{}`. I cannot control that of the second level (nested) environment, or the third, whether it is `itemize`, `enumerate`, etc. What might be the problem? Below is the MWE and output. Adding `\fontsize{}{}` inside the nested environments do not change the output either.

```
\documentclass[12pt, xcolor=pdftex,dvipsnames,table,aspectratio=169]{beamer}     
\usetheme{default}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{array,bm,booktabs,multirow,multicol,pgfplots,setspace,subfig,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\fontsize{7}{7pt}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item a
        \item b
        \begin{itemize}
            \item c
            \item d
        \end{itemize}
        \item e 
        \begin{itemize}
            \item f
            \item g
            \begin{itemize}
                \item h
                \item i
            \end{itemize}   
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item 1
                \item 2
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{itemize}
        \item j
    \end{itemize}

\end{frame}
```

[image]

Comment: The second answer on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33969/changing-font-size-of-selected-slides-in-beamer provides a possible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution: just put the nested itemize environment inside a `scalebox` and `minipage`, adjusting parameters accordingly, like:

```
\scalebox{0.85}{\begin{minipage}{1.2\textwidth}
 % itemize environment here...
\end{minipage}}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
\documentclass[12pt, xcolor=pdftex,dvipsnames,table,aspectratio=169]{beamer}     
\usetheme{default}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array,bm,booktabs,multirow,multicol,pgfplots,setspace,subfig,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\setbeamerfont*{itemize/enumerate body}{size=\fontsize{5}{7}}
\setbeamerfont*{itemize/enumerate subbody}{parent=itemize/enumerate body}
\setbeamerfont*{itemize/enumerate subsubbody}{parent=itemize/enumerate body}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item a
        \item b
        \begin{itemize}
            \item c
            \item dbo
        \end{itemize}
        \item e 
        \begin{itemize}
            \item f
            \item g
            \begin{itemize}
                \item h
                \item i
            \end{itemize}   
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item 1
                \item 2
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{itemize}
        \item j
    \end{itemize}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 `\fontsize` doesn't take dimensions, so it should just be `\fontsize{5}{7}` (or perhaps `\fontsize{5}{6}`)